# How to make a reusable TextPopUp in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am having trouble building a reusable SwiftUI text pop up view.  I think the problem is the binding but I not sure.  It is supposed to be a ContextMenu, but the reason I am not using ContextMenu is it does not show enough lines of text.

So far I have this...

```
struct TextPopUpView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var oracleViewModel: OracleViewModel
    @Binding var showPopover: Bool
    var displayedText: String
    var popUpText: String

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(displayedText)")
            .font(.title)
            .fontWeight(.bold)
            .onLongPressGesture {
                self.showPopover = true
        }
        .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
            Text("\(self.popUpText)")
                .frame(width: 250.0)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.showPopover = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And than I implement it for a particular view like so...

```
TextPopUpView(showPopover: $showPopover, displayedText: oracleViewModel.***someElement***, popUpText: oracleViewModel.getDescriptionFor***SomeElement***()).environmentObject(oracleViewModel)
```

where 'someElement' is the particular element text and popup text I want to show.

The problem is when I use TextPopUpView more than once in a view, the Popup view only displays the text for the last implementation on the said page.

I am guessing I am doing something wrong in the implementations of a reusable view, but I am not sure what.   Any suggestions?

EDIT:  (Example Used in code)

```
struct TopView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var oracleViewModel: OracleViewModel
    @State private var showPopover: Bool = false

***Blarg Blarg Blarg***

            VStack{
                VStack {
                    Text("RUNE")
                        .font(.system(size:10))
                        .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
                    TextPopUpView(showPopover: $showPopover,
                                  displayedText: oracleViewModel.rune,
                        popUpText: oracleViewModel.getDescriptionForRune()).environmentObject(oracleViewModel)
                }
                .padding(.bottom)
                VStack {
                    Text("ELEMENT")
                        .font(.system(size:10))
                        .padding(.bottom, 5.0)
                    TextPopUpView(showPopover: $showPopover,
                                  displayedText: oracleViewModel.element,
                                  popUpText: oracleViewModel.getDescriptionForElement())
                                    .environmentObject(oracleViewModel)
                }
            }

***Blarg Blarg Blarg***

}
```

(For some reason I only get the description for the Element, when I long press either view the TextPopUp is attached to)

Comment: Would you show the code that uses TextPopUpView, those which in several places, including corresponding states? ... I suppose you refer them to one state, because in my test all works fine if each of them depends on own state.

Comment: Sure No Problem. (Added)